# DC output of DC-controlled SSR does not turn off in simple circuit

Tags: dc, solid-state-relay

The following simple circuit turns a LED ON/OFF. It includes:

- DC power supply 12V ([EDR-120-12](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/mean-well-usa-inc/EDR-120-12/7702913?s=N4IgTCBcDaIKIBEBKBaAjGADOiBdAvkA))
- SSR (rated for DC input and output, DR10D12, [datasheet](http://www.crydom.com/en/products/catalog/seriesone-dr-din-rail-mount.pdf))
- LED, 400mA, 2.85V forward (L2-MLN1-S, [datasheet](https://www.bivar.com/parts_content/Datasheets/L2-MLXX-S.pdf))
- resistor 50 Ohm
- pushbutton (PVA6LRE21241, [datasheet](https://sten-eswitch-13110800-production.s3.amazonaws.com/system/asset/product_line/data_sheet/224/PVA6.pdf))
  [image]

My problem is that the SSR output remains ON and can only be turned OFF with turning the power supply OFF.

When the pushbutton is ON:

- the small LED of the SSR is ON
- the LED is ON and the measured current flowing through it is 198 mA (supposed to be 195 mA = (12 V - 2.85 V)/47 Ohm)
- when there is no load at the SSR output, the resistance across the SSR outputs (1/L1, 2/T1) is 0 Ohm (and my multimeter says it is the same potential)

When the pushbutton is OFF:

- the small LED of the SSR is off
- the LED is ON and the measured current flowing through it is 185 mA
- when there is no load at the SSR output, the resistance across the SSR outputs (1/L1, 2/T1) is 3 MOhm

With the SSR LED turning correctly ON and OFF I believe that the issue is on the output side.

I do not understand where these 185 mA come from when the pushbutton is OFF. (I think the 13 mA difference (198 mA - 185 mA) is the small LED of the SSR turning ON and OFF).

I've read about possible solutions (use a bleeder resistor in parallel to the load to remove a leaking current?) but I am still not sure I understand what is happening here, so I thought I would ask a clear question here for the record.

Thanks for any help

Edit: for clarity, removed the circuit for the LED illumination of the pushbutton

Edit: answering questions from comments

- "Is this SSR designed for DC?" from @user253751. Yes it is:
  [image]

[image]

Diagram of the SSR with DC control input and DC output.

[image]

Comment: The datasheet notes that in the off state, there is a maximum leakage current of 0.1mA. That is enough to very slightly light an LED (but not as brightly as the ~20mA that would run through it with the SSR conducting fully). Could you be seeing this faint glow as the LED being on?

Comment: Also, it looks like your terminals are backwards - swap 3/4 and swap 1/2. I think this must be a drawing issue only though, as otherwise nothing should work properly.

Comment: Thanks @SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica. It is not a faint glow, I've measured it to be 185 mA, I've edited the post. I've edited the drawing also, thanks, that was only a drawing issue indeed.

Comment: That looks you have tyristor output. Check carefully the part number or may be label wrong.

Comment: Thanks @user263983. Part number is correct: it is DR10D12, ordered from Digikey, part number CC1767-ND. The printed label on the SSR is unmistakably correct.

Comment: Is this SSR designed for DC?

Comment: Thanks @user253751. Yes it is, added the relevant parts of the spec sheet in the post

Comment: It does say "maximum turn-off time: 1/2 cycle" - odd for DC.

Comment: Thanks again @user253751. I added the small notes saying "Turn-off time for DC output 300 usec"

Comment: I suppose I should've noticed that you specified the SSR and even included a link to the datasheet. I didn't need to ask you. Whoops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm puzzled: I entirely re-wired the circuit from scratch, and it is now working as expected. I do not understand what was happening.
Sorry for the false alarm, hopefully this question still provides a clean record of a working configuration.

Comment: There is still something wrong about your diagram, which appears to have the LED reverse biased.

Comment: Thanks @MathKeepsMeBusy, edited.